# How can I change the frequency of a sine wave from 5 MHz to several smaller ones, e.g. 1kHz, 100Hz and 1Hz?

Tags: frequency, frequency-divider

5 MHz is the frequency of the quartz based oscillator. I get a clean, sine wave output. I would like to (divide) this signal into several, lower frequencies in steps, e.g. 1kHz, 100Hz and 1Hz. I don't want to use a microprocessor but an analog circuit instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your own work, ideas and findings so far. At the moment, this is a couple of lines that read as expecting a long and detailed circuit design in return.

Comment: What is the purpose of the signals? What level of distortion is allowed? What peak-to-peak voltage do you require? Please edit this information into your question rather than bury it in the comments.

Comment: @Transistor the purpose of this circuit is to create a "reference bank" of several audio frequencies that will be used to tune synthesisers.

Comment: Use DDS products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want sine waves as the output? If so, there are several viable approaches:

1. Have voltage-controlled-frequency sinewave oscillators, and control their frequency using a PLL referenced to the 5MHz oscillator. E.g. a Wien bridge oscillator for each frequency, and use a [vactrol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistive_opto-isolator) and a PLL to keep its frequency and phase slaved to the 5MHz reference.
2. Divide the 5MHz down to desired frequencies using digital dividers, then low-pass the square waves to yield sine waves.
3. Use a counter, a bunch of magnitude comparators, and a wide-input XOR gate (parity generator) to make [magic sine waves](https://www.tinaja.com/msquant/retry_m/xxxx.shtml), then low-pass filter them using a low-order lowpass. The magic sinewave pulse trains only have the fundamental and very high harmonics, with nothing in-between, so should be easy to do.
4. Use a high frequency VCO and a PLL to generate 5MHz+Δf, then mix the two and low-pass the output.
5. Use a direct digital synthesis chip capable of low frequency output. The chip can be initialized using a long parallel-input, serial-output shift register with inputs set to configure the frequency as needed.

For #1, another approach might be to make a Bubba oscillator - four stages that shift 45° in phase in series - using an op-amp with current-controllable bandwidth. An LM146/LM346 would work well as an oscillator - it's a quad op-amp with bandwidth adjustable with a control current. A PLL's output would control the current source biasing the op-amp.

For #2, design 4th-order op-amp-based low-pass filters using a tool, then implement them, and you should get a reasonable-enough sine wave.

> 5 MHz is the frequency of the quartz based oscillator. I get a clean, sine wave output.

Just because you have a 5MHz sine wave doesn't mean it can be directly "converted" to a lower frequency. In almost all viable approaches, that sine wave will be either fed to a PLL as a reference input, or will have to be converted to a square wave to feed digital circuits.

And also there's no way to say how "clean" the output is unless you show spectrum analyzer plots.

Comment: The approach numer 2. was my first idea - I should mention it in my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki #2 and #3 are very similar. #3 uses more digital logic but has much lower distortion since even a first-order filter will get rid of higher harmonics to a good degree. A 5MHz clock may be a bit on the low side for #3 though. The faster the clock, the better.

Comment: #2 is fine for generating a square wave from 5Hz to 5MHz. But now you'll have to open a new question along the lines of "How can I design a low pass filter that can sweep from 5Hz to 5MHz?"

Comment: @td127 Assuming a fixed frequency it'll be no problem. One classic solution is a switched-capacitor filter running synchronously with the square wave source. The MFxx filter family from NatSemi did that. There are modern replacements although they need more external parts.

Comment: @td127 - No, I don't think I need so wide range LPF. I would rather filter just a few, selected frequencies. For example I can create a 7490 combined divider circuit and filter only selected frequency outputs. That's what I have in mind at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [DDS chip](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9837.PDF) such as AD9837 to create a sine wave directly from the 5MHz clock (preferably with a bit of filtering on the output).

> at a 5 MHz clock rate, the AD9837 can be tuned to 0.02 Hz
> resolution.

You would need something with a 3-wire SPI interface to configure the chip at power-up.

Comment: Yep, and the configuration can be done using an auxiliary oscillator and a bunch of shift registers in series, with dip switches (can be rotary ones) to set things up. I've done that and it's a beautiful kludge but pretty robust.

Answer (score 1):

How about using another sine wave oscillator at 5.1 MHz to get the 100 kHz difference frequency:

[image: 5 MHz to 100 kHz]

Here is the simulation to get 100 Hz. For such small differences in frequency, two 5 MHz crystal oscillators could be used, and frequency tweaked using various trimmer capacitors.

[image: 5 MHz to 100 Hz]

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> ... the purpose of this circuit is to create a "reference bank" of several audio frequencies that will be used to tune synthesisers.

Then you don't need sine waveforms. Also, I suspect, that tuning in octaves would be more useful and they're obtained by dividing by two. e.g., using standard tuning of A<sub>440</sub> you might use 55 Hz, 110 Hz, 220 Hz, 440 Hz, etc.

[image]

*Figure 1. The 4020 makes octave division very simple. Image source: [Electronics Club](https://electronicsclub.info/cmos.htm).*

All that is required is to choose a master oscillator frequency that is a power of two multiple of the chosen note. This is much simpler than any analogue circuit.

> e.g. 1kHz, 100Hz and 1Hz.

1 Hz isn't in the audio band - for humans, at least.